# Hector Mapping PointCloud2 Map

Tags: ros, laser, ros-melodic, ubuntu, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day everyone.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with RO Melodic.

Currently i am using hector mapping to obtain a map and view it in RVIZ. It subscribed to laser scan type topic and published an OccupancyGrid type map.

Right now i would like to do a similar thing with slight different, subcribed to laser scan type topic and published a PointCloud2 type map. Free, occupied and unknown space will be differentiate via color.

I believe it is possible but I am lack of experience to do so. Therefore I would like to get some advices from you guys on how to accomplished this task.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318003/hector-mapping-pointcloud2-map/) by [KinWah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38047/kinwah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully publish a PointCloud Map that almost the same/exactly the same compared with OccupancyGrid Map.
The reason I am doing so is I would like to publish sensor reading in the form of PointCloud.
With the Map in form of PointCloud, I may merge both sensor reading and map.

Below is the codes that I have used to accomplish this task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import struct
from std_msgs.msg import Header, ColorRGBA
from nav_msgs.msg import OccupancyGrid, MapMetaData
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pcl2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2, PointField

def translate(value, leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax):
    # Figure out how 'wide' each range is
    leftSpan = leftMax - leftMin
    rightSpan = rightMax - rightMin

    # Convert the left range into a 0-1 range (float)
    valueScaled = float(value - leftMin) / float(leftSpan)

    # Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
    return rightMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan)

def point_cloud_xyzrgb(x, y, map_data, origin_x, origin_y, resolution):
    
    points = [] 
    lim_x = x
    lim_y = y
    for i in range(lim_x):
        for j in range(lim_y):
            x = translate(i,0,lim_x-1,origin_x,abs(origin_x)) #use float(i) or translate(i,0,lim_x-1,origin_x,abs(origin_x))
            y = translate(j,0,lim_x-1,origin_y,abs(origin_y)) #use float(j) or translate(j,0,lim_x-1,origin_y,abs(origin_y))
            z = 0
            pt = [x, y, z, 0]
            if map_data[i+ lim_x * j] == 0:
                r = 255
                g = 255
                b = 255
            elif map_data[i+ lim_x * j] == 100:
                r = 0
                g = 0
                b = 0
            else:
                r = 255
                g = 0
                b = 0
                
#           r = int(x * 255.0)
#           g = int(y * 255.0)
#           b = int(z * 255.0)
            a = 255
            rgb = struct.unpack('I', struct.pack('BBBB', b, g, r, a))[0]
            pt[3] = rgb
            points.append(pt)
    
    header = Header()
    header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    header.frame_id = 'map'
    fields = [PointField('x', 0, PointField.FLOAT32, 1),
          PointField('y', 4, PointField.FLOAT32, 1),
          PointField('z', 8, PointField.FLOAT32, 1),
          PointField('rgb', 12, PointField.UINT32, 1),
          # PointField('rgba', 12, PointField.UINT32, 1),
          ]
    point_cloud = pcl2.create_cloud(header, fields, points)
    point_cloud_map.publish(point_cloud)


def mapCB(data):
    map_header = data.header
    map_x = data.info.width
    map_y = data.info.height
    resolution = data.info.resolution
    origin_x = data.info.origin.position.x
    origin_y = data.info.origin.position.y
    map_data = data.data
    point_cloud_xyzrgb(map_x, map_y, map_data, origin_x, origin_y, resolution)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    rospy.init_node('PointCloud_Map_Generator')
    point_cloud_map = rospy.Publisher('point_cloud_map', PointCloud2, queue_size=10)
    raw_map = rospy.Subscriber("map", OccupancyGrid, mapCB)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    
    try:
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            rate.sleep()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

---

Originally posted by [KinWah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38047/kinwah/) with karma: 91 on 2019-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0